# How to parse a date column as datetimes, not objects in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to create DataFrame from a csv with one datetime-typed column.

Follow [the article](https://towardsdatascience.com/4-tricks-you-should-know-to-parse-date-columns-with-pandas-read-csv-27355bb2ad0e), the code should create needed DateFrame:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data/data_3.csv', parse_dates=['date'])
df.info()
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column   Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------   --------------  -----         
 0   date     3 non-null      datetime64[ns]
 1   product  3 non-null      object        
 2   price    3 non-null      int64         
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 200.0+ bytes
```

But when I do exacly the same steps, I get object-typed date column:

```
df = pd.read_csv(path, parse_dates=['published_at']) 
df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 100000 entries, 0 to 99999
Data columns (total 6 columns):
 #   Column           Non-Null Count   Dtype  
---  ------           --------------   -----  
 0   name             100000 non-null  object 
 1   salary_from      48041 non-null   float64
 2   salary_to        53029 non-null   float64
 3   salary_currency  64733 non-null   object 
 4   area_name        100000 non-null  object 
 5   published_at     100000 non-null  object 
dtypes: float64(2), object(4)
memory usage: 4.6+ MB
```

I have tried a couple of various ways to parse datetime column and still can't get a DateFrame with datetime dtype. So how to parse a column with datetime type (not object)?

Comment: it implies the values are not parsable. what's happenning when you do `pd.to_datetime(df.published_at)` after reading in the data? probably an error and it would hopefully tell an example on why it could not datify

Comment: Yes, I get `ValueError: Tz-aware datetime.datetime cannot be converted to datetime64 unless utc=True`. So how to parse lines like `2003-01-31T18:24:11+0300`?

Comment: Have you tried, `infer_datetime_format = True` when you load csv? Likewise you can try `utc=True`

Answer (score 1):

When loading the csv, have you tried:

```
df = pd.read_csv(path, parse_dates=['published_at'], infer_datetime_format = True)
```

And/or when converting to datetime:

```
pd.to_datetime(df.published_at, utc=True)
```

Comment: The `infer_datetime_format` didn't help, but `utc=True` works, thanks. But it transfers the datetime to UTC format. Is there way to parse datetime64 with offset?

Comment: In that case, have you tried `utc=False` (as opposed to `None`, the default)? I'll edit answer if it works.

Comment: The behavior is explained in more details in the doc: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html#to-datetime-tz-examples